# Java FX GUI can´t load unknown source

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

The problem is that when I start the program I always get an exception saying that the source file can´t be found. I already used the internet for resolving the problem by using the exception message as search argument for google. But I didn´t find a solution.

**Exception Message:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at com.kw.overtaker_monitoring.Main.start(Main.java:18)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/924394080.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1051754451.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/389777815.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Error Message in SceneBuilder:**

*No injectable field found in FXML Controller class for the id 'btnSelectDatabaseFile'*

For further information, I´ll give you the code of my classes below

**Main.java (Main class):**

```
package com.kw.overtaker_monitoring;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        try 
        {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.fxml (GUI File):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="561.0" prefWidth="830.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="kw.IO.Controller">
   <children>
      <Accordion layoutX="22.0" layoutY="68.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="7.0" />
      <Accordion layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="639.0" prefWidth="889.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="16.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0">
        <panes>
          <TitledPane animated="false" text="First">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="187.0" prefWidth="234.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button id="btnAddSizeToFolderName" fx:id="btnAddSizeToFolderName" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="84.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#RunFolderRenaming" text="Add size to foldername" />
                        <TextField id="txtSrcPath" fx:id="txtSrcPath" layoutX="112.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="671.0" />
                        <Label layoutX="22.0" layoutY="18.0" text="sourcepath" />
                        <Label layoutX="22.0" layoutY="48.0" text="destinationpath" />
                        <TextField id="txtDestPath" fx:id="txtDestPath" layoutX="112.0" layoutY="44.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="672.0" />
                        <CheckBox fx:id="chkIncludeSubDirs" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="88.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Only subdirs" />
                        <Separator layoutX="-5.0" layoutY="75.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="808.0" />
                        <Separator layoutX="-4.0" layoutY="116.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="808.0" />
                        <TextField id="txtSrcPath" fx:id="txtOldFileName" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="126.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="176.0" />
                        <TextField id="txtSrcPath" fx:id="txtReplaceWith" layoutX="282.0" layoutY="126.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="176.0" />
                        <Label layoutX="212.0" layoutY="130.0" text="replace with" />
                        <Button id="btnAddSizeToFolderName" fx:id="btnReplace" layoutX="469.0" layoutY="126.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#RunFileRenaming" text="replace from all files in folder" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
          <TitledPane animated="false" text="Movie Database Tools">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TextField editable="false" layoutX="141.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="651.0" />
                        <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#btnSelectDatabaseFile_Clicked" text="Select Database File" />
                     </children></AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
          <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 3">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="434.0" prefWidth="731.0" />
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
        </panes>
      </Accordion>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Controller.java (Controller class):**

```
package kw.IO;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private Button btnAddSizeToFolderName;
    @FXML
    private Button btnReplace;

    @FXML
    private Button btnSelectDatabaseFile;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtSrcPath;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtOldFileName;//TODO: übergeben
    @FXML
    private TextField txtReplaceWith;//TODO: übergeben

    @FXML
    private CheckBox chkIncludeSubDirs;


    private Operator operator = new Operator();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // this starts the a thread with the function of renaming folders by adding their size to them

    public void RunFolderRenaming(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Button wurde geklickt!");
        System.out.println(txtSrcPath.getText());
        operator.StartFolderRenaming(txtSrcPath.getText().toString(), chkIncludeSubDirs.isSelected());
    }

    public void RunFileRenaming(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("File renaming button clicked!");
        operator.ReplaceFromFiles(txtSrcPath.getText(), txtOldFileName.getText(), txtReplaceWith.getText());
    }

    public void btnSelectDatabaseFile(ActionEvent btnSelectDatabaseFile_Clicked)
    {
        System.out.println("Button Select Database File was clicked!");
    }

}
```

Please help me with my problem?

Kind regards

Prouder

Comment: Is your `MainWindow.fxml` under `com/kw/overtaker_monitoring` inside resources dir?

Comment: Remove `@FXML private Button btnSelectDatabaseFile;` from your controller class and rename `btnSelectDatabaseFile(...)` to `btnSelectDatabaseFile_Clicked(...)`.

Comment: A whole bunch of your controls have `id="..."` where they should have `fx:id="..."`. Not sure if that is the only problem...

Comment: At Dimitry Ginzburg: The "MainWindow.fxml" file is in the src folder but not in the "com.kw.IO package"

Comment: At ItashiUchiha: I tried your tip but it didn´t work                                                                                                               At James_D: I also tried your tip but there was no difference